# i am getting this error while connecting to database in mongoDB , what should i do

Tags: mongodb, mern

const serverSelectionError = new ServerSelectionError();
I am getting this error while connecting to the database in MongoDB, what should I do

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to assist. What is the full error/stack trace that is being reported? What is the database topology that you are using? Has this ever worked or is this a new error that started recently?  What versions of MongoDB and the Node drover are you using? etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a node version greater than 17, try replacing localhost in the URL with 127.0.0.1.
You can copy the following code.

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/<your DB name>',{useNewUrlParser:true});
```

Comment: you have to write the name of the database name you want to create or connect to in place of "<your DB name>